# Solr PhraseQuery With Wildcard

Tags: solr, lucene, wildcard

I have been struggling with **Solr v4.10.2** with a **PhraseQuery with wildcard**!
My field definition is below:

```
<!-- Search field -->
<field name="title" type="text_pt_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<!-- Field definition -->
<fieldType name="text_pt_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />

        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_pt.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" /> -->

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>

    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_pt.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" /> -->

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Let's suppose I have the following value added to the index of the field above (portuguese):

```
Teste de texto; Será quebrado em espaços em branco!
```

And the values added to the index, based on the analyzer chain will be (from Solr "Analysis"):

```
etset teste ;otxet texto; odarbeuq quebrado socapse espacos !ocnarb branco!
```

Today, I can search, for example:

```
title:teste
title:(teste texto)
title:(teste de texto)
title:("teste de texto;") // (PhraseQuery) matches because of ";" in the end of the string
```

But, if I try to search (PhraseQuery):

```
title:("teste de texto")
    "parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(title:\"teste ? texto\")"

title:("teste de texto*")
    "parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(title:\"teste ? texto*\")"
```

No results are returned.

I have read about possible solutions to this, but none of them seems to work:

- MultitermQueryAnalysis
- Complex Phrase Query Parser

And I just can't understand why the query with the wildcard in the end: **"*"** does not work, no results are returned.

Some comments:

- I don't have control over what is entered in the search, it is entered by a user of the application, but I would like it to work like a "file listing", like a simple "glob";
- Today I can't change my tokenizer to: "StandardTokenizerFactory" (that in this case would work), because I need to search for e-mails, words with colon, for example;
- I tried the: "KeywordTokenizer", but I have the same behavior as above;
- I read about: "ShingleFilterFactory", but my index would be huge, because I need to index full texts (with more than 30000 chars);

Could you please help me understand what happens, if there is a way to make a PhraseQuery with a wildcard work and what are my options?

Please, let me know if you need further information and thanks a lot for your attention and help!

Comment: Wildcards in phrases are not supported by the standard query parser, simple as that.  [See the documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Wildcard_Searches).  You'll need to use complexphrase (or fix your analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the documentation! I have read that in several places, just want to confirm it. You commented **complexphrase**, I tried that, but I had the same behavior. I used this [link](http://yonik.com/solr-4-8-features/) and the query: **{!complexphrase}title:"teste de texto*"**, but no results. About: fix the analysis, what did you mean? I tried to use: "KeywordTokenizerFactory", but it only works if I use "RegexpQuery": **title:(/.*teste de texto.*/)**. Do I have other options?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem with the configuration below:

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />

    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />

    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
```

And search using the Complex Phrase Query Parser, like below, now returns the desired document:

```
{!complexphrase df=title}"teste de texto*"
```

I think that the problem with my last field setup was the StopFilterFactory, as the Complex Phrase Query Parser documentation states: "It is recommended not to use stopword elimination with this query parser." [1]

I've done some tests and, so far, this setup fits my needs (queries).

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser